# string will not cout first part

Tags: c++, string, cout

I'm writing a game in c++ and i want it to output a string character by character and slow down the out put with the Sleep() function. The string is :

```
string output = "It is Super Effective!" + '\n';
```

when I try `cout << output` it returns `"r Effective"` with no new line
the code for the display function is

```
void textDisplay(string s){
    s = " " + s;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        char c = s[i];
        cout << c;
        Sleep(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that in your loop, the chars might get buffered, and not be displayed.  You can overcome this with "cout << c << std::flush".

Answer (score 9):

It's because `"It is Super Effective!" + '\n'` is being interpreted as the pointer to the C-string plus the integral value of the character `\n`, which is 10 in ASCII. This is happening *before* the assignment to the C++-string.

You'll see, if you count ten characters in from the start of your C-string, you do *indeed* end up at the `r`.

So here's what's happening, in detail and sequence:

- The expression `"It is Super Effective!"` is being interpreted as a char pointer to the initial `I` character (a C-string).
- You're then adding ten (the integral value of `\n`) to that to get a pointer to the `r` (still a C-string).
- That C-string `"r Effective!"` is then being used to construct the C++-string.

In graphical form:

```
base +  0: | I  | -------+
base +  1: | t  |        |
base +  2: |    |        |
base +  3: | i  |        |
base +  4: | s  |        |
base +  5: |    |     Add ten
base +  6: | S  |        |
base +  7: | u  |        |
base +  8: | p  |        |
base +  9: | e  |        |
base + 10: | r  | <------+
base + 11: |    |
base + 12: | E  |
  :
base + 21: | !  |
base + 22: | \0 |
```

You can change it to add the character to the C++ string rather than the C string:

```
string output = "It is Super Effective!";
output += '\n';
```

but I'm not entirely certain why you wouldn't just do:

```
string output = "It is Super Effective!\n";
```

---

One other thing you may want to watch out for. It's possible that the flushing of characters to standard output will only occur when a newline is sent, meaning that you'll seem to get the *entire* string in one hit, some seven minutes or so after you expected the first character to appear.

If that happens, remember to flush the stream after every character:

```
cout << c << flush;
```

Comment: Sorry I don't really know pointers that well can you tell me a little more?  Ohhhh thank you for making it bit more clear for me  I just put it in the "" I don't why I had it out of them.

Comment: @lark, I've expanded the answer considerably, hopefully it explains in enough detail for you. If not, simply let me know which part you're having trouble with.

Comment: Alternatively, in C++14 we can use [`std::literals::string_literals::operator""s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) via `using std::literals::string_literals;` and `std::string output="It is Super Effective!"s + '\n'`;

Answer (score 3):

In this context, the `+` is not joining the character to the string literal, but is returning a pointer value offset by `\n` bytes. In ASCII, this would be `0x0A`, or 10.  This is because the string literal is an array of `const char`, which then decays to the address of its first element. The `+` operator then offsets 10 characters past that element.

```
                     1
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
|I|t| |i|s| |S|u|p|e|r| |E|f|f|e|c|t|i|v|e|!|
```

You can correct this by initializing the `string` first, and then appending.

```
string output = "It is Super Effective!";
output += '\n';
```

Or, you can use string literal concatenation, by dropping the `+` and using `"\n"` instead:

```
string output = "It is Super Effective!" "\n";
```

Or just make the whole thing a string, which would be most clear.

```
string output = "It is Super Effective!\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

When the C++ compiler encounters an operator in your program, it performs overload resolution, just like for overloaded functions.  Binary `operator+` has many overloads, but you care about these two:

```
std::string operator+(std::string, char)   // string concatenation

const char* operator+(const char*, std::ptrdiff_t)     // pointer arithmetic
```

Other answers have explained what these two alternate meanings of `+` are, I will show you how the compiler determines that the second meaning is better.

Your actual parameters have type `const char[N]` and `char`.  The first argument can implicitly convert to `const char*` using array-to-pointer decay, and to `std::string`, by using array-to-pointer decay followed by a "user-defined conversion" (`std::string`'s implicit constructor).  The second argument can convert to any other integral type, including `std::ptrdiff_t`, via an implicit widening.

All the different types of conversions are ranked according to a table in the C++ Standard, and in this table, user-defined conversions are used only as a last resort.  So the pointer arithmetic interpretation wins.

Comment: Is the second overload valid? I thought you cannot have an overload for fundamental types. Or are you thinking of how it's performed "internally" by the compiler?

Comment: @vsoftco: You cannot write such an overload, but many of them are provided by the language.  See section 13.6, `[over.built]`.  "The candidate operator functions that represent the built-in operators deﬁned in Clause 5 are specified in this subclause. These candidate functions participate in the operator overload resolution process as described in 13.3.1.2 and are used for no other purpose."

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that the standard defines them.

Comment: "For every cv-qualiﬁed or cv-unqualiﬁed object type `T` there exist candidate operator functions of the form `T * operator+(T *, std::ptrdiff_t);
T & operator[](T *, std::ptrdiff_t);
T * operator-(T *, std::ptrdiff_t);
T * operator+(std::ptrdiff_t, T *);
T & operator[](std::ptrdiff_t, T *);`"